# AutoHotKey Mouse down Continue press a key, until mouse up

Tags: autohotkey, mousedown

I was trying make a script that enable me to continue press a certain key, for example "1", when I hold my left mouse click for more than 0.5 sec, and will continue until I release the left mouse button.

Hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: Are you sure? This would disable things like drag & drop, unless you make this function application specific or run the script selectively (pause).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. I used the Middle Mouse button to test.

I commented out the lines that are application specific.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Put at the top of your script.

MButton:: ; Start this script when the Middle Mouse Button is pressed
;ifWinActive, Your Application Name ; Place the application name as in the windows title.
;{
    KeyWait, MButton, T0.5 ; Wait for MButton to be released within 0.5 sec
    if  (ErrorLevel) ; Not released within 0.5 sec.
    {
        Send, {1 Down} ; Press 1 down, will not autorepeat unless placed in a while loop
        KeyWait, MButton ; Wait for Mbutton to be released
        Send, {1 Up} ; Once MButton is released, undo the press 1 down
    }
    else ; If MButton was released within 0.5 sec.
    {
        Click ; press click
    }
;}
;else
;{
;   Click ; perform normal click behaviour when outside of the target application
;}
Return
```

Comment: I am pretty bad at mindreading, so "don't seem to be able to get this script to work" can mean several things to me. Can you be more specific. Where are you running into problems?